# Table to table copy across different sheets using function and text composed ranges

Tags: excel, vba

I already have a table prepared in one sheet of the Excel document that will be not modifiable that looks like this

```
name | info | info2 | info3 | ammount
-----|------|-------|-------|--------
name | info | info2 | info3 |    0
name1| info | info2 | info3 |    0
```

and it contains a full list of items with amounts defaulted to 0.

On a second sheet, I have a table that is identical in columns but has nothing stored inside, the user will input the name in this second table and the macro will search for it on the first table and copy the row to the second table.
The user will modify the amount on the second table and then store it back on the first table so as to have:

```
name | info | info2 | info3 | amount
-----|------|-------|-------|---------------------
name | info | info2 | info3 | different value now
name1| info | info2 | info3 |    0
```

I attempted to use the macro recorder to manually find out which steps would be needed and I tried to code from that but I found some issues:

- I lacked a reliable way to copy the table row without having to copy the entire Excel row so I used a range instead
- I lack a way to keep the cell ranges variable so as to compose a range with the row indicator that will change depending on the match function and the column letters which will always remain the same since the whole row is needed.

I am sure there is a smarter way to do this, currently, I use a match function to find out the row number that the name typed out on table2 is on table1

So in the short example there it would return 1.

At this point I would like to be able to use that "1" to compose a range: "A2:E2" in this case and copy the range on the second table so that the name overlaps the name used for the search.

This would give me a copy of only the rows containing the names the user types out in table2.

Now the user will modify the amount on table 2 then return the row to table1 using the same process used to take it to table2 but in reverse:
knowing the table2 row number and column range compose the range to copy and find which row to overwrite trough the match function.

At the moment I am trying to understand how the process would work for 1 match but I will need to have the process search multiple matches for which I assume a recursion would be needed to keep track of the lines searched and where to copy the results in table1.

I am sure there must be an easier and smarter way to do this but my experience with VBA is really shallow, any suggestion will be appreciated.

Note: the info columns contain important info that won't be modified by the end user so it won't be necessary to copy it back, I just thought it would be easier to copy the whole row instead of the single cell at least as a first step.

On a finishing note: I was asked to log all the user made changes (so the returning values from table2) with a timestamp if possible to an external file for backup security, I am unaware if that is possible and how would it be tackled.

I managed to solve one of the issues I had by using this code:

```
=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("'sheet1'!B";(CONFRONT(A2;Table1[Column1];0)+1));TRUE)
```

By using this code I can update all the other columns related on the content of the first table by searching which row has the same name as the user types out.

Comment: I know indirect can be used to interpret a string as an address but since i need a range of addresses it wouldn't work i believe.
I am using  the function concatenate to build a string referring to my range of one row of the table1 at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since nobody answered and I found a working solution (for how unrefined it may be)
I am going to share it in the hope that if someone will need something of this kind will find this helpful.

I had already updated my question with the code I used to populate table2 depending on a search of the "name" column so as to have only the rows the user will be interested to change the quantity at a later time.

This is the macro I used in a button to update the value directly in table1 (so it would reflect the change on table 2 as well).

```
Sub button2_Click()
    Dim cb As Shape
    Dim x As String
    x = Range("J2").Value

    Set cb = ActiveSheet.Shapes("chkbx2")

    If cb.OLEFormat.Object.Value = 1 Then
        Range(Range("M2")).Value = Range("E2").Value - Range("J2").Value
        MsgBox "Subtracted " + x + " part(s) to component: " + Range("A2").Value
    Else
        Range(Range("M2")).Value = Range("E2").Value + Range("J2").Value
        MsgBox "Added " + x + " part(s) to component: " + Range("A2").Value
    End If
End Sub
```

- "E2" contains the address of the cell containing the last value shown
  in table2 (which is linked to table1)
- "J2" contains a number I want    to modify the amount by "M2"
  contains this formula:
  =CONCATENATE("'sheet1'!B";(CONFRONT(A2;Table1[Column1];0)+1)) which yelds the address of the original box in Table1 referred to the quantity
- chkbx2 is a checkbox that allows switching from addition to subtraction
- MsgBox is a simple popup textbox that tells you what operation has
  been done on which column name so you know what happened to the
  numbers
- "A2" contains the name of the item

I did not manage to find a way to recursively apply this and thus each line has it's own code to retrieve from table1 and each button + checkbox combo has it's macro with different cell coordinates, but this works.