# Copy/pasting from one document to another based on matching data

Tags: excel, vba

Before I start, I have zero knowledge of creating macros in Excel, and while I’d love for someone to leave a fully working solution, I would also be very grateful for a small point in the right direction where I can hopefully try to write something myself.

I am trying to make a spreadsheet of music data taken from Apple’s “Apple Music Play Data.csv”, which is set up somewhat like this:

```
Song1, Artist1, Album1

Song1, Artist1, Album1

Song1, Artist1, Album1

Song2, Artist1, Album1

Song2, Artist1, Album1
```

etc.

Where the number of lines equal the number of times a song was played (the above example would be Song1 playcount = 3, Song2 playcount = 2).

However, a majority of the Album fields are blank or incorrect. I have another document where each song corresponds to its artist and album, like this:

```
Song1, Artist1, Album1

Song2, Artist1, Album1

Song3, Artist1, Album1

Song4, Artist2, Album2
```

etc.

My question is, how do I create a macro that takes the song and artist from Apple’s document, searches my other document for a match, and then copies the album name from my document to Apple’s document in the correct cell? I found an answer similar to what I am looking for, however I am still having some problems. This is the code I found and edited, where w1(Sheet2) is my document and w2(Sheet1) is Apple's document:

```
Sub Test()

 Dim w1 As Worksheet, w2 As Worksheet
 Dim c As Range, FR As Long

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False

 Set w1 = Workbooks("Book2.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet2")
 Set w2 = Workbooks("Book2.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1")


 For Each c In w1.Range("A2", w1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
     FR = 0
     On Error Resume Next
     FR = Application.Match(c, w2.Columns("A"), 0)
     On Error GoTo 0
     If FR <> 0 Then w2.Range("C" & FR).Value = c.Offset(0, 2)
 Next c
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The issue is that first and foremost, this is only searching by Song Title, rather than both Song Title and Artist. This is a problem if multiple artists have the same song title. Secondly, the output to Apple's document only happens the first time a song appears, e.g.

```
Song1, Artist1, CorrectAlbum1

Song1, Artist1, BlankAlbum1

Song1, Artist1, BlankAlbum1

Song2, Artist1, CorrectAlbum1

Song2, Artist1, BlankAlbum1
```

At this point, I simply have no idea what I should be adding or changing to get the desired result, as well as very little understanding of what the code I have used means. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Couldn't you just use VLOOKUP and do this without programming?

Comment: What you are trying to get is a way to write next to your song name in your own file the name of the album pulling it from a list you have in a second worksheet, correct? If that is the case, you could achieve this by using Excel functions, [This is an issue that is somewhat similar i encountered recently, i think it could help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53335777/table-to-table-copy-across-different-sheets-using-function-and-text-composed-ran)

Comment: I would suggest something like **`Index+Match`** for this